# Why does copied text have 0~ in front and 1~ at the end?

Tags: clipboard

When I copy text to the clipboard in Ubuntu it automatically adds the text `0~` in front and `1~` at the end, like:

```
wget https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/download/1.19.2.1/pandoc-1.19.2.1-1-amd64.deb
======>
0~wget 0~https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/download/1.19.2.1/pandoc-1.19.2.1-1-amd64.deb1~
```

I guess was input method caused, how to fix it?

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)

# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi
alias vi=vim
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the copy command used in this instance?

Comment: I have provided an example ,
when copy "wget https.....", after pasted, it will be "0~wget https...1~"
,use mouse copy text

Comment: Can you run `cat /home/$USER/.bashrc` and paste that into your question.

Comment: all other lines was default line, for too long, I cannot paste it, sorry for such a long time to response
alias vi=vim
export TERM=xterm-256color

Comment: I've recently observed this  in Lubuntu 16.04 LTS, though in my case it seemed to go away by itself. Is this with regular Ubuntu? (Or Lubuntu? Xubuntu?) What's the output of  `lsb_release -a`? Does this persist after logging out and back in or rebooting? Does this *always* happen? Are there programs where it doesn't? Does it happen even when you copy text out of and back into one application like Gedit? Does it only happen with text copied to or from the Terminal? (Desktop environments don't use `.bashrc` so I'm not sure why @George requested it.) You can **[edit]** again to add this info.

Comment: This resembles [bug 1506166](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vte3/+bug/1506166)/[bug 1350334](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vte/+bug/1350334), [bug 1552943](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/1552943), and [bug 347308](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jedit/+bug/347308), though I don't know how related it is to any of them. *If* it always and only happens in copies/pastes involving terminal windows and persists after a reboot or full logout (not just a screen lock), my guess is it's a bug. With more information it should be possible to figure this out.

Comment: it's ubuntu gnome

Comment: if I use gedit or atom, it didn't have such a problem when copy and paste

Comment: yes it persist after rebooting, it happened copy to Terminal, I remember after  installed fctix and google pinyin, these happened, never before